# How to build blender (as python module) without having to clone the complete repository?

Tags: compile

I'd like to build Blender v3.0.0 as a python module in a docker container. Generally, the process seems to be pretty straight-forward, thanks to the multitude of tutorials.

However, cloning the blender repository with

`git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git`

takes a very long time. I thought that I could speed it up by making only a shallow clone of the repository using

`git clone -b v3.0.0 --single-branch https://git.blender.org/blender.git` or

`git clone https://github.com/blender/blender.git --depth 1 --branch v3.0.0`

but that gives me the following error during `make update`:

> Blender git repository is in detached HEAD state, must be in a branch

Is there a way around this?

Comment: How about you create a branch after cloning the repo? like `git checkout -b my-branch` ?

Comment: Well... I think that fixed it. :-) That was easier than suspected. I think I misinterpreted the error... Thank you very much. If you write an answer (maybe with a short explanation), then I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I just posted it as an answer, using a different but equivalent command, as found in git documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Blender's build process depends on a the git repository being checked out to a branch.

In Blender's git repository, `v3.0.0` is a `tag`, rather than a `branch`.

The shallow clone works with tags, but once it finishes, the local repository is not checked out to any actual git branch, hence the error message about `detached HEAD state` (c.f. git documentation on [checking-out tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_checking_out_tags)).

To solve the problem, simply create a branch, with the current contents of the repo.

For example:

```
git switch -c <new-branch-name>
```

Then, you should be good to go :)